# Magento translating "Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax)"

Tags: magento, translate

So I'm trying to translate "Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax)" and "Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax)". I tried it with inline translation wich worked for "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)" "Grand Total (Incl.Tax)", but didn't work for the shipping lines. Tried to find them in .csv files in Mage_Sales.csv and Mage_Adminhtml.csv to be exact, but didn't find them. Only thing I can think of is to translate them in tax.php, but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels with Excl. Tax and Incl. Tax are placed in Mage_Tax.csv

In order to not searching for individual file you can use translate.csv file in your theme where you can translate everything. Here is my detailed article about that file  - [Editing translate.csv file](http://blog.belvg.com/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html)

Comment: Thank you that worked for emails, but still is in English in PDF invoice(I'm using Easy PDF Invoice extension) and in admin panel, wich I don't really care about, but I guess the two are connected. And thanks a lot for the guide, didn't know that before!

Comment: glad that helped,for adminhtml you can create use translate.csv in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/<yourlocale>/translate.csv  if it helped you can consider accepting an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Alright that translated it for admin panel too, but still didn't change the PDF file for some reason. Though I didn't find those lines in Mage_Tax.csv either, but I guess my best bet now is to contact Easy PDF Invoice developers as the problem seems to be in the extension. Thanks for answering so quickly!